# Get the north/south west/etc of a \draw rectangle, circle, etc

Tags: tikz-pgf

Suppose I have drawn a rectangle using the `\draw` function:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \draw (0,0) rectangle (1,1);
\endtikzpicture}
```

What is the proper way to access the "principle sides" (north,northwest,west,etc.) of the bounding box of this path (note that it could also be a circle, a smooth bezier curve, etc.)? Ideally I want to do something like:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \draw[name=foo] (0,0) rectangle (1,1);
  \node[left=1cm of foo.east] {bar};
\endtikzpicture}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Thanks to Schrödinger's cat, you can use the `local bounding box` to define and use that to access the desired coordinates:

[image]

This allow for other things to be drawn (the circle in this case) and the actual bounding box to be remain intact (draw in blue).

### Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \draw (1,1) circle (0.5cm);
  
  \begin{scope}[local bounding box=MyRectangle]
      \draw (0,0) rectangle (1,1);
  \end{scope}
  
  \draw [red, thick] (MyRectangle.south west) -- (MyRectangle.north east);
  
  \draw [blue] (current bounding box.south west) rectangle (current bounding box.north east);
\end{tikzpicture}%
\end{document}
```

Comment: I like this, but what if other elements were present in the drawing before rectangle?

Comment: You're welcome!

Comment: Shorter: `\scoped[local bounding box=MyRectangle] \draw (0,0) rectangle (1,1);`

Comment: @HenriMenke: Good suggestion, but there may be more complicated drawing in there, so the `scope` environment might be better.

Answer (score 4):

You could just use a node with `outer sep=0pt` and the appropriate `minimum width` and `minimum height`. The default shape is `rectangle`.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \path (0,0) node[draw,minimum width=1cm,minimum height=1cm,anchor=south
  west,outer sep=0pt](foo){};
  \draw[dashed,red] (0,0) rectangle (1,1);
  \node[left=1cm of foo.east] {bar};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

The red dashes are only to show that the paths coincide. If it is a square, you could also use `minimum size`. The analogous statements apply to circles and so on. The `shapes.geometric` library has several geometric shapes, and there are other `shapes` libraries.